TypeError: this._firestore.native.documentGet is not a function (it is undefined)
I'm trying to implement a "recommended friends" feature, and users have "following" and "followers" lists in firestore database. For some reason I keep running into this TypeError saying that the function I'm using is not a function.
This is the code snippet for the screen where this issue is happening:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, TextInput, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

type Friend = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    username: string;
};

function PeopleQuickAddScreen({ route, navigation }) {
    const params = route.params;
    const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState('Quick Add');
    const [recommendedFriends, setRecommendedFriends] = useState<Friend[]>([]);
    const [visibleFriendsCount, setVisibleFriendsCount] = useState(3);
    const [friendsError, setFriendsError] = useState<string | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchRecommendedFriends();
    }, []);

    const fetchRecommendedFriends = async () => {
        try {
            const userRef = firestore().collection('users').doc(params.userId);
            const userSnapshot = await userRef.get();

            if (!userSnapshot.exists) {
                setFriendsError('User not found.');
                return;
            }

            // Get the university from route params
            const userUniversity = params.university;
            
            // Get the list of user IDs the current user is following
            const followingSnapshot = await userRef.collection('following').get();
            const followingIds = followingSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.id);

            // Query all users from the same university excluding the current user and those already followed
            const usersSnapshot = await firestore()
                .collection('users')
                .where('university', '==', userUniversity)
                .get();

            const friends = usersSnapshot.docs
                .filter(doc => doc.id !== params.userId && !followingIds.includes(doc.id))
                .map(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    return {
                        id: doc.id,
                        name: data.name || 'No Name',   // Default to 'No Name' if undefined
                        username: data.username || 'Unknown', // Default to 'Unknown' if undefined
                    };
                }) as Friend[];

            // Set recommended friends to be displayed
            setRecommendedFriends(friends.slice(0, 10)); // Example to show first 10 recommendations
            setFriendsError(null);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching recommended friends:', error);
            setFriendsError('No friends to recommend, invite some to join CampusWatch!');
        }
    };

In Podfile I have:
  pod 'RNFBApp', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app'
  pod 'RNFBFirestore', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore'

ChatGPT told me to make this file:
// firebaseConfig.js
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "MY_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "MY_AUTHDOMAIN",
  projectId: "MY_PROJECTID",
  storageBucket: "STORAGEBUCKET",
  messagingSenderId: "SENDERID",
  appId: "APPID",
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  firebase.app(); // if already initialized, use that one
}

export default firebase;


Replaced the text with all my keys, obviously. However, I don't think it helped with anything.
All my pods are of the most latest versions. If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it!
